# How to change default line width in Package Editor code formatter?

Tags: front-end

My question is how to change the default line width in Package Editor (`File > New > Package/Script > Wolfram Language Package (.wl)`)?

Context: I tried using different editors for my `.wl` scripts - both Visual Studio Code with the official WR plugin, as well as IntelliJ IDEA with [@halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan)'s Wolfram Language plugin, and I realized that I like the simplicity of the built-in package editor. In particular, I like the simple reloading - just press "Run All Code", and the fact that the UI/color scheme/etc. are consistent with the Notebook editor.

There is one downside: while I'm mostly OK with "Format Cell", it seems to default to a very short line width. Looking at `/Applications/Wolfram Desktop.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Components/CodeFormatter/Kernel/CodeFormatter.wl` (which seems to be the code behind that button), I see that `$DefaultLineWidth = 78` and there are comments that it was discussed in [Live CEOing Ep 392](https://youtu.be/href-3TZRxM?t=1842) and references to that [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822.html#section-2.1.1). I guess it was all relevant in days of Teletypes etc., but I have a Ultrawide screen display and I would rather have wider but shorter programs.

The [CodeFormatter documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CodeFormatter/ref/CodeFormat.html) describes a `"LineWidth"` parameter which is indeed working as expected (the second line is how I would like to see the code been formatted). What is the **least hacky way** to change that value in Package Editor?

[image: default and desired formatting]

E.g., the following code doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
Needs["CodeFormatter`"]
CodeFormatter`$DefaultLineWidth = 140
```

I probably know enough of FrontEnd internals to tinker with the default stylesheets (or create my own) to manually override this, but I'm wondering if there is an easier or more straightforward way?

Comment: Ok, so here is a partial solution: the above change to the `$DefaultLineWidth` does seem to affect the code behind the `Code Formatting` palette, which also seems to offer ability to have custom line breaking rules and a way to save them into presets. Hopefully one day it will make into the main "Format Cell" button.

Comment: [Here is](https://youtu.be/href-3TZRxM?t=3022) where they discuss the line width in the Live CEOing video